# Extracting Category IDs and Category Labels from URLs Using R

Tags: regex, r

Suppose I have the following links:

```
<a class=\"MainCategory\"href=\"/cp/3951?povid=cat1070145-env172199-moduleA080112-lLinkGNAV_Electronics_Computers\">Computers</a>
<a href=\"/browse/electronics/desktop-computers/3944_3951_132982/?_refineresult=true&catNavId=3951&povid=cat1070145-env172199-moduleA080112-lLinkGNAV_Electronics_Computers_Desktops\">Desktops</a>
<a href=\"/cp/Laptops/1089430?povid=cat1070145-env172199-moduleA080112-lLinkGNAV_Electronics_Computers_Laptops\">Laptops</a>
```

Is there an automated way to extract the following IDS : 3951, 132982 & 1089430 and their corresponding labels: Computers, Desktops, and Laptops?

Comment: Why don't you supply use with some example URLs, and then show us how you want the output to look like? Include what you have tried already.

Comment: Sorry, I just formatted HTML markup.

Comment: If you have arbitrary data like the following and the ID is always in different places, then it will be more complicated.

Comment: Are the links being retrieved from a website or stored?

Comment: I retrieved them from a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your URLs are in a vector like the following

```
vec <- c("<a class=\"MainCategory\"href=\"/cp/3951?povid=cat1070145-env172199-moduleA080112-lLinkGNAV_Electronics_Computers\">Computers</a>",
         "<a href=\"/browse/electronics/desktop-computers/3944_3951_132982/?_refineresult=true&catNavId=3951&povid=cat1070145-env172199-moduleA080112-lLin kGNAV_Electronics_Computers_Desktops\">Desktops</a>",
         "<a href=\"/cp/Laptops/1089430?povid=cat1070145-env172199-moduleA080112-lLinkGNAV_Electronics_Computers_Laptops\">Laptops</a>")
```

you can use regular expressions to extract the information:

```
data.frame(ID = sub(".*[0-9]+_[0-9]+_([0-9]+).*", "\\1", 
                    sub(".*[^0-9]([0-9]+)\\?povid.*", "\\1", vec)),
           Label = sub(".*>(.*)</a>$", "\\1", vec))

#        ID     Label
# 1    3951 Computers
# 2  132982  Desktops
# 3 1089430   Laptops
```

Comment: Maybe you should mention that is not a good idea to use regular expression to extract HTML attributes...